# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: when launching pyspark

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I just download the spark on Mac, the version I download is the latest one 
pre-built for Hadoop 2.6

When I try to install this, on the Terminal I type bin/pyspark
I got is the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    
org/apache/spark/launcher/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.launcher.Main
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I looked up on Google and some answer says I need to update my Java, I just downloaded latest Java version but still get the error message

Can anyone help me on this please. Please explain in detail as I'm new to Spark

Comment: There's a couple of things you need to check to get it working:

- Make sure that the latest java binaries are in your path
- Ensure that you have SPARK_HOME set to the correct path

Comment: 1) run java -version in your terminal 2)did you download source code or binary 3) check your permissions for the spark folder. did the download spark from the same user?

Comment: Thanks for that, I don't quiet understand how I can do that. Could you send some code, also about the path, how do I change it. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi I just checked that my java version is 1.8.0_65 which I think should be the updated one

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem when I was trying to install Spark 1.6.2 on Mac OS (10.11 El Captain).

After installing the latest Java JDK (Java SE Development Kit 8), I had no problem to run `pyspark`. You could download the latest JDK from Oracle's website.

Good luck!

BTW, I also installed the legacy Java 6 runtime for OS X 10.11 El Capitan provided by Apple because I encountered an error message `To use the "java" command-line tool you need to install a JDK` in the beginning of the installation process.